# MarkLogic database deleted on deleting the field range index

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

There is a bug in ML v10.0-4.2. When we create a field range index through admin API and delete it through admin UI, the database configuration gets deleted and the database becomes inaccessible. This bug has been documented by MarkLogic (BUG-54775) and has been fixed in later versions.

At the moment, we are not up for a MarkLogic upgrade. We are looking for an immediate fix to restore our database/data. The database forests are still available but we are unable to attach them to the newly created database (with the same name).

Any resolution is much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is slightly confusing. Is the issue with the database configuration or the forest configuration? Please also include the exact errors that you are getting..  some errors hint at manual (intrusive) steps that can be done in the configuration by a qualified person. Of course, first try the simple step as laid out by Mads.

Answer (score 2):

You could delete the most recent (now corrupted) `/var/opt/MarkLogic/databases.xml` on each of the hosts in the cluster. MarkLogic will now start with the previous configuration file instead.